# Screen - switch tabs in subscreen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I use this in my .screenrc:

```
bindkey ^[q prev
bindkey ^[w next
```

to switch between windows with alt+w/q
If I open screen in screen, I can switch like: ctrl+a+a + number, but I would like to id for example with: alt+a/s

Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. As far as there is no `if` statement in `.screenrc` syntax, we should use shell. Assuming your shell is GNU Bash, you can put this in the `.bashrc`

```
case "$TERM" in
    screen*)
        [[ $PARENTTERM == screen* ]] && {
            screen -X eval 'bindkey ^[s prev' 'bindkey ^[a next'
        }
        ;;
esac
```

(`case "$TERM" in` block must already exist)

And this in your `.screenrc`:

```
setenv PARENTTERM "$TERM"
```

So `^[a` / `^[s` will be bound in every Screen, starting inside other Screen. There is no need to unbind `^[q` and `^[w` but you can do it.